# Hwo to set colors in coverflow carousel in swiper.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, carousel, swiper.js

I have to create a carousel in NextJs with swiper.js this is the design -

[image]

This is my code - >

```
"use client";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/effect-coverflow";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import { TServiceRepository } from "@/common/types/services";
import { Pagination, Autoplay, EffectCoverflow } from "swiper/modules";
import "./swiper.css";
import CardPanel from "./CardPanel";
import { useMediaQuery } from "usehooks-ts";
import { useState } from "react";

type Props = {
   services: TServiceRepository[] | [];
};

const getCardPanelColor = (
   index: number,
   activeIndex: number,
   realIndex?: number
) => {
   if (index === realIndex) return "bg-white";
   if (index < activeIndex) return "text-white bg-teal-600";
   if (index > activeIndex) return "text-white bg-orange-600";

   return "bg-white";
};

const SwiperCarousel = ({ services }: Props) => {
   const matches = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 768px)");
   const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
   const [realIndex, setRealIndex] = useState(0);

   return (
      <Swiper
         effect="coverflow"
         grabCursor={true}
         modules={[Pagination, EffectCoverflow, Autoplay]}
         centeredSlides={true}
         slidesPerView={3}
         coverflowEffect={{
            rotate: 0,
            stretch: matches ? 350 : 0,
            depth: 100,
            modifier: 1,
            slideShadows: true,
         }}
         pagination={{ clickable: true }}
         autoplay={{ delay: 3000, disableOnInteraction: false }} // Add autoplay settings
         speed={1100}
         loop={true}
         className="our-service-carousel min-h-[400px]"
         onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
            setActiveIndex(swiper.activeIndex);
            setRealIndex(swiper.realIndex);
            console.log("log: sw", swiper.activeIndex);
         }}
      >
         {services.map((service, index) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={service._id}>
               <CardPanel
                  item={service}
                  className={getCardPanelColor(index, activeIndex, realIndex)}
               />
            </SwiperSlide>
         ))}
      </Swiper>
   );
};

export default SwiperCarousel;
```

And it makes the carousel look like this ->

[image]

So it is not always accurate when slides change colors.

Please help me here to fix this issue and make the carousel consistent. Also please suggest if any other package I have to use to achieve this result.